# Prove that $I = \int_0^{m(m+1} y_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges and $I \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

My problem is stated as follows

> Let $y_0(x) = x, \ \: y_1(x) = \sqrt{x}, \ \: y_{n+1}(x) = \sqrt{y_n(x) +x\,} \ $.     Now define
>
> $ \displaystyle \hspace{3cm} I_n = \int_0^k y_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x $
>
> Prove that
>
> - $I_n$ converges for all $k$
> - $I_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ **if** $k = m(m+1)$ where $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Does the second bulletpoint hold if the condition is replaced with **if and only if**?

The limit case $n \to \infty$ can be handles as follows
$$y = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \cdots}} \ \Rightarrow \ y^2 = x + y$$
Hence $y = \left( 1 + \sqrt{1+4x}\right)\!/2$. Now 
$$
I = \lim_{n\to\infty} I_n = \int_0^{k} y \,\mathrm{d}x
  = \int_0^{k} \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2} \,\mathrm{d}x
  = \frac{1}{12} + \frac{k}{12} (1+4k)^{3/2}
$$
Given that $k = m(m+1)$ the integral reduces to 
$$
I = \frac{3}{2}m^2+m+\frac{2}{3}m^3 \, \in \, \mathbb{Q}
$$
However this does not prove convergence, nor the more general problem. Eg that the above holds for each $y_n$ not just the limiting case.